# Why I get 404 error for some files when running the nodejs app on http server?

Tags: node.js

I get 404 error for some files when running the nodejs app on http server error message is like below

> Error: Request failed with status code 405
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at settle (settle.js:18)

And there was no error when running on localhost.

Comment: Do you use a framework like `express`, `hapi` ?

Comment: err... it's error **405** http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message reports an error **405**, which means the web server refused your action. http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

ie: you sent a POST method but your server doesn't allow it.

Check your web server's configuration and fix it accordingly.